# Django - Select option from two dropdown menu and display filtered result in a third dropdown menu

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have got two dropdown options, country and number service location. Options for both can be selected from their respective dropdown. 
My objective is to display correct telephone number based on the selected country and number service location. You will also see my attempt to implement this functionality using Ajax in views below.

Model created here -

```
class DID_Number_Assignment_Model(models.Model):       #DID Number Assignment
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_service_location = models.ForeignKey(Number_Service_Location_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    did_selector = models.ForeignKey(DID_Definition_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views.py

```
def did_assignment_form(request, id=0, *args, **kwargs):
 if request.method =="POST":
        if id==0:
            form = DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form(request.POST)
            if request.is_ajax():
                country = request.GET.get('country')
                number_service_location = request.GET.get('number_service_location')
                filters = {'country': country, 'number_service_location': number_service_location}
                dids_searched = DID_Definition_Model.objects.filter(**filters)
                data = []
                for dids in dids_searched:
                    data.append({
                        'country': dids.country,
                        'number_service_location': dids.number_service_location})
                    return HttpResponse({
                        'success': True,
                        'data': data,
                        }, content_type=content_type)
            else:
                return HttpResponse({
                    'success': False,
                    'message': 'Only AJAX method is allowed.'
                    }, content_type=content_type)
```

template html file here -

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <!--{{form|crispy}} !-->


    <div class="row", style = "position:relative; left:57px; top:100px">
        <div class="col-md-7"> {{ form.country | as_crispy_field }}  </div>
        <div class="col-md-7"> {{ form.number_service_location | as_crispy_field }}  </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('change', '.filter-dropdown', function() {
    var country = $('#countryDropdown').children('option:selected').val();
    var number_service_location = $('#number_service_locationDropdown').children('option:selected').val();

    if (country !== "" && number_service_location !== "" ) {
        var data = {
            'country': country,
            'number_service_location': number_service_location
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/did_definition_list/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    // render did_number from `response.data`
                } else {
                    // show message from `response.message`
                }
            },
            error: function(errorResponse) {
                // show error message
            }
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
});
</script>
```

Model form below -

```
class DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DID_Number_Assignment_Model
        fields = ('country','number_service_location','did_selector', 'usage_assignment', 'employee_fullname', 'employee_email',  'subscriber_department' )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        super(DID_Number_Assignment_Model_Form,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        defs_with_no_assignments = DID_Definition_Model.objects.filter(did_number_assignment_model__isnull=True)
        available_did= defs_with_no_assignments.values_list('did_number', flat=True)

        # TO SET drop down default text for a field , optional -
        self.fields['did_selector'].empty_label = "Select"
        self.fields['did_selector'].queryset = DID_Definition_Model.objects.filter(did_number__in=available_did)
```